# TypeScript: Look up field's type based on another field

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an interface like this:

```
interface Cat {
  weight: number;
  name: string;
  adoptable: boolean;
}
```

I want to define the following interface that can be used to set values on `Cat`:

```
interface CatUpdate {
  field: keyof Cat;
  value: ???
}
```

and I want TypeScript to enforce that value is the appropriate type based on field. E.g., this should be invalid:

```
const x: CatUpdate = {
  field: "name",
  value: 12
}
```

How do I define the type of `CatUpdate.value`?

Answer (score 9):

My inclination would be to make `CatUpdate` a union type and not an interface, like this:

```
interface Cat {
  weight: number;
  name: string;
  adoptable: boolean;
}

type PropUpdate<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { field: K; value: T[K] }
}[keyof T];


type CatUpdate = PropUpdate<Cat>;
/* 
type CatUpdate = {
    field: "weight";
    value: number;
} | {
    field: "name";
    value: string;
} | {
    field: "adoptable";
    value: boolean;
}
*/
```

That should work well enough on your mentioned use case:

```
const x: CatUpdate = {
  field: "name",
  value: 12
} // error!
```

And you should be able to compose those (`CatUpdate | DogUpdate`) if you need to, although without a particular use case it's hard to know if such composition is appropriate (Can `Cat` and `Dog` be discriminated from each other?  That is, is `Cat & Dog` impossible?  If `Cat & Dog` is possible, then `CatUpdate | DogUpdate` can only be used to update a `Cat & Dog`.  If it's impossible, then `CatUpdate | DogUpdate` should probably be replaced with a discriminated union instead like `(CatUpdate & {kind: "CatUpdate"}) | (DogUpdate & {kind: "DogUpdate"})`.)

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzMg3gWAFDLIDuEwA5gBZgBcyIArgLYBG0A3PoSHIxLQM5gooMhwLI4AEwD2ABzBxmAGz7Jm06SrggxAX3z4wAT1koAClDkBVWZIwQAPABVkEAB6QQk-smnMAVhAIYAB8yAC82JzIANoA0sigyADWEEbSMMhOALq0WMgwwBBKkrRxbMgAbnBK9KpO8dnI+ni6ManpmTliBnjGpmgYNnaQEcgW1rb2DuihYgD0AFTIhiYos8P2Y7jihIXFpcgARCTkVEdihITVtaoMLOz4usgAPlG7BUUltEfcvBfRa41OoCIQiPSvd5XT4HH5SOQKZQQAEfG4gtQaLQ6J74RbzXoIaQgQTINy0DZTUaRHZ7L6HX48ZEAGmiaNUAEYAExPZDzeauKCWKAAQiAA)

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct one

Comment: Great technique, been looking for this for a long time.

Comment: Hi when i use this i have the problem that the CatUpdate always includes 'undefined' as valid type, when one of the Cat's properties is for example "string | undefined" , how can i get rid of that?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a generic type:

```js
interface CatUpdate<T extends keyof Cat> {
  field: T;
  value: Cat[T];
}
```

It works, but it means you'll need to be a little bit more verbose when creating the object.

```js
// Error
const x: CatUpdate<"name"> = {
  field: "name",
  value: 12
}

// No error
const y: CatUpdate<"name"> = {
  field: "name",
  value: "Dave"
}
```

One solution would be to use a function for instantiation which can infer the type based on the parameters:

```js
function getCatUpdate<T extends keyof Cat>(field: T, value: Cat[T]): CatUpdate<T> {
    return {
        field,
        value
    }
}
```

Which you could call like:

```js
// Error
const x = getCatUpdate("name", 12);

// No error
const y = getCatUpdate("name", "Dave");
```

Comment: With the generic type on the interface, I'm running into an issue where the interface is unioned with a bunch of other types, e.g. `PetUpdate` = `CatUpdate` | `DogUpdate`, but TS complains that I need to provide T in `CatUpdate` when defining `PetUpdate`. I'm thinking I'll probably have to redo the structure entirely to get what I want.

Comment: Yeah, this won't work well with unions. Still, it shouldn't be necessary to use unions unless I'm missing something (assuming `Cat` extends `Pet`):
`
interface PetUpdate<TPet extends Pet, TKey extends keyof TPet> {
  field: TKey;
  value: TPet[TKey];
}

function getCatUpdate<T extends keyof Cat>(field: T, value: Cat[T]): PetUpdate<Cat, T> {
    return {
        field,
        value
    }
}
`
EDIT: ugh, excuse the code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, TypeScript does not have what you are looking for, but you can hardcode the types:

```js
type CatUpdate 
    = { field: 'weight', value: number }
    | { field: 'name', value: string }
    | { field: 'adoptable', value: boolean }
```